# Error occurs during Cashfree payment gateway integration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cashfree

Every attempt to integrate the Cashfree payment gateway into my Laravel application results in the same error.

> [2024-03-26 17:19:44] local.DEBUG: Input data for payment initiation:
> {"orderId":"inv004","orderAmount":"0963462492","customerName":"Manuel
> Portillo","customerEmail":"teodoro.almaraz8@rezult.org","customerPhone":"7365435505","returnUrl":"https://payment.remwhacktechnologies.com/payment/callback","version":"2021-05-21"}
> [2024-03-26 17:19:45] local.ERROR: Error initiating payment: 400 -
> {"message":"version value should be 2021-05-21 or 2022-01-01 or
> 2022-09-01 or
> 2023-08-01","code":"request_failed","type":"invalid_request_error"}

I have changed the version year and tried all possibilities, but I consistently receive the same error. The code below is from my controller, where I am initiating my payment

```
public function initiatePayment(Request $request)
{
    try {
        // Perform validation on $request->input() if necessary

        $clientId = 'TEST10152050eee78259b07eef2a86fc05025101'; // Your Cashfree client ID
        $clientSecret = 'cfsk_ma_test_303cb4db3e6ad084b222959b7014db1a_0161753d'; // Your Cashfree client secret

        $orderId = 'inv004'; // Generate a unique order ID
        $orderAmount = $request->input('amount');
        $customerName = $request->input('name');
        $customerEmail = $request->input('email');
        $customerPhone = $request->input('phone');
        $returnUrl = 'https://payment.remwhacktechnologies.com/payment/callback'; // Ensure the return URL is correct
        $version = '2021-05-21'; // Set the correct version parameter

        // Log input data for debugging
        Log::debug('Input data for payment initiation:', [
            'orderId' => $orderId,
            'orderAmount' => $orderAmount,
            'customerName' => $customerName,
            'customerEmail' => $customerEmail,
            'customerPhone' => $customerPhone,
            'returnUrl' => $returnUrl,
            'version' => $version,
        ]);

        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'X-Client-Id' => $clientId,
            'X-Client-Secret' => $clientSecret,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ])->post('https://sandbox.cashfree.com/pg/orders', [
            'orderId' => $orderId,
            'orderAmount' => $orderAmount,
            'customerName' => $customerName,
            'customerEmail' => $customerEmail,
            'customerPhone' => $customerPhone,
            'returnUrl' => $returnUrl,
            'version' => $version, // Include the version parameter
        ]);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            // Redirect user to payment gateway
            return redirect($response['paymentLink']);
        } else {
            // Log error response
            Log::error('Error initiating payment: '.$response->status().' - '.$response->body());

            // Handle unsuccessful response
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error initiating payment']);
        }
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        // Log exception
        Log::error('Error initiating payment: '.$e->getCode().' - '.$e->getMessage());

        // Handle request exception
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Error initiating payment']);
    }
}
```

I have attempted to use all available versions, including 2021-05-21, 2022-01-01, 2022-09-01, and 2023-08-01, but the error persists. As a newcomer to PHP and Laravel, I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

This is deprecated method. Instead of this try cashfree latest php sdk i.e. https://github.com/cashfree/cashfree-pg-sdk-php

Install using composer

```
composer require cashfree/cashfree-pg
```

For your use case sample code is

```
public function initiatePayment(Request $request)
{
    Cashfree::$XClientId = "XXXXXXXXX_Client_ID";
    Cashfree::$XClientSecret = "XXXXXXX_Client_Secret_Key";
    Cashfree::$XEnvironment = Cashfree::$SANDBOX;
    $cashfree = new Cashfree();

    $x_api_version = "2022-09-01";
    $orderId = 'inv004'; // Generate a unique order ID
    $orderAmount = $request->input('amount');
    $customerName = $request->input('name');
    $customerEmail = $request->input('email');
    $customerId = $request->input('customerId');
    $customerPhone = $request->input('phone');
    $returnUrl = 'https://payment.remwhacktechnologies.com/payment/callback'; // Ensure the return URL is correct
    $create_orders_request = new CreateOrderRequest();
    $create_orders_request->setOrderId($orderId);
    $create_orders_request->setOrderAmount($orderAmount);
    $create_orders_request->setOrderCurrency("INR");
    $customer_details = new CustomerDetails();
    $customer_details->setCustomerName($customerName);
    $customer_details->setCustomerId($customerId);
    $customer_details->setCustomerEmail($customerEmail);
    $customer_details->setCustomerPhone($customerPhone);
    $create_orders_request->setCustomerDetails($customer_details);
    $order_meta = new OrderMeta();
    $order_meta->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);
    $create_orders_request->setOrderMeta($order_meta);

    try {
        $result = $cashfree->PGCreateOrder($x_api_version, $create_orders_request);
        dd($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception when calling PGCreateOrder: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Make sure you have imported all necessary dependency

Comment: thank you for helping me but i a getting an error " Class "App\Http\Controllers\Cashfree" not found " i am sure i am not importing some dependency but on github also i cannot find any dependency can you help me with it